# Image, text/text and image in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get the following design. Consider that it is a list item.

[image]

But my following design, it does not give me that design.The textviews come on the top of left image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/userimage" />
  <TextView
    android:text="Text1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"/>
  <TextView
    android:text="Text2"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
 </RelativeLayout >
```

[image]

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is better suited for this task

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a LinearLayout use a RelativeLayout, and for the TextViews use:

android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage" and

android:layout_alignTop="@id/userimage" or

android:layout_alignBottom="@id/userimage"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
    tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/userimage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/userimage"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/arrow"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        tools:text="Text1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        tools:text="Text2" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black"
    tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try to play with different layouts when you have time, it will help you greatly in the future.

**Edit**:
Better solution for centering TextViews.

Comment: What happened? Can you describe the issue now?

Comment: TextViews are on the top of the left image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondline"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example username"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used some `dp` sizes that you did not use and added a few other things, but I guess you can change it so that it suits your desire. I did try use the same names as you did. Overall this should work if you tweak it a bit.

Comment: @hotspring try this new code and make sure to adjust some of the parameters (sizes, names) if they are wrong. This should work if you adjust a few things.

Comment: I have copied your code and run it, please see my updated output. It is too strange.

Comment: @hotspring I updated my answer. Try copy-pasting my code now, without rearranging anything.

Comment: I have done it, I could only see left image and right image, not textviews.

Comment: @hotspring Ok, try changing the `layout_width="0"` of the TextViews to `layout_width="match_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in text2 use it , it would work

```
<TextView
android:text="Text2"
android:layout_below="@id/username"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```